# Create a new .txt file as output with extra text from commands

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to write a function `annotate()` which takes a file name as a parameter and prints it to a new file `out_annotated.txt` with:

1. the original text
2. row number
3. the total amount of words up to and including that row.

Let's say my  `.txt` file is as following:

```
hello you
the sun is warm
I like dogs
```

I want the output to be:

```
hello you 1 2
the sun is warm 2 6
I like dogs 3 9
```

The code I used before was

```py
def main():
    length = count_rows("file.txt")
    print(length)

def count_rows(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
        return i + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But how do I progress into making a new `.txt` file with the output including row numbers and the total amount of words?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
def AppendNumbers(input_file, output_file):

    # initialize variables:
    total_number_of_words = 0

    with open(input_file, 'r') as in_file, open(output_file, 'w+') as out_file:

        for line in in_file.readlines():

            # get number of words on each line:
            number_of_words_per_line = len(line.split(' '))

            # add to total word count:
            total_number_of_words += number_of_words_per_line

            # add words to new line:
            new_line = line.replace('\n', '')
            new_line = new_line + ' ' + str(number_of_words_per_line) + ' ' + str(total_number_of_words) + '\n'

            # write new line to outfile:
            out_file.write(new_line)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    input_file = 'file.txt'
    output_file = 'out_file.txt'

    AppendNumbers(input_file, output_file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, tried from both comments and they both worked really good. I understand as well now, Thank you!

Comment: @PythonDaniel Didn't you ask to output the line, line number and total amount of words?

Comment: @PythonDaniel but this writes the line, word count for the line, and total wordcount. It is not what you asked for...

Answer (score 0):

You can create the name of your output file using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html):

```
base, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
out_path = base + "_annotated" + ext
```

Now you can open them both: one for reading one for writing, while holding a total words counter. Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) as you did is good to keep track of line numbers, but according to your example you want to start from `1`. We will [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the lines to count words:

```py
total_words = 0
with open(fname) as f_in, open(out_path, 'w') as f_out:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f_in, start=1):
        total_words += len(line.split())
```

Lastly, because you want to add at the end of each line, you need to avoid the ending `'\n'`, so you can write the lines after you [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) them and add the row number and word count:

```
        f_out.write("{} {} {}\n".format(line.strip(), line_num, total_words))
```

All together we have:

```py
import os

def count_rows(fname):
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    out_path = base + "_annotated" + ext

    total_words = 0
    with open(fname) as f_in, open(out_path, 'w') as f_out:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(f_in, start=1):
            total_words += len(line.split())
            f_out.write("{} {} {}\n".format(line.strip(), line_num, total_words))
```

Running this on a file named `file.txt` with the contents as your example, produces a file called `file_annotated.txt` with contents of:

```
hello you 1 2
the sun is warm 2 6
I like dogs 3 9
```

Comment: This works just fine, thanks a lot! Really appreciated the in depth explanation as well!